# Angular click event on button wont fire until clicked twice

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, frontend

I'm currently creating an application in angular. The module I am working on gives you ability to join or create a room.

The initial ui of the room module:
https://gyazo.com/81afe2b5f7119326d00b518fc4e0979f

upon clicking on "join room" button we go to the join ui:
https://gyazo.com/0728a182b27a143fcefd9d71d0c33c44

once I click on the Join button i get an error of:

> ERROR DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

However, once i click the join button for the second time I am able to connect to the websocket server and get no issues

I believe it has something to do with the use of `*ngIf` and the dom not loading properly
the main code for the HTML is :

```html
<button *ngIf="isEnterRoomShown" id="createRoomBtn" mat-raised-button (click)="createRoom()">Create Room</button>
  <button *ngIf="isEnterRoomShown" id="joinSessionBtn" mat-raised-button (click)="joinRoom()">Join room</button>
  <div [hidden]="isEnterRoomShown">
    <button  id="join" mat-raised-button (click)="join()">Join</button>
  </div>
```

and the component:

```
  createRoom() {
    const name = this.nameInput.nativeElement.value;
    this.websocket = this.wsService.initWebsocket();
    const wsData = {
      message: "create-room",
      name,
    };
    this.rService.username = name;
    if (this.websocket.readyState === 0) { }

    this.waitForSocketConnection(this.websocket, () => {
      this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(wsData));
    });
  }

  joinRoom() {
    this.isEnterRoomShown = !this.isEnterRoomShown;
  }

  join() {
    if (!this.websocket) {
      this.websocket = this.wsService.initWebsocket();
    }

    const name = this.nameInput.nativeElement.value;

    this.rService.username = name;

    if (this.websocket) {
      this.websocket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          message: "join-room",
          name,
          id: this.roomId.nativeElement.value,
        })
      );
    }

    this.outRoom = false;

    this.sessionId = this.roomId.nativeElement.value;
  }
```

I am still pretty new to stackoverflow and angular development, please let me know if you need extra clarification on anything. I have tried to search for similar questions on stackoverflow and have found no answers.

Comment: Consider adding images to the post; if gyazo.com deletes them there will be dead links in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ngIf it creates and destorys HTML DOM Elements. So in this case instead of using ngIf, use hidden directive

`[hidden]="!isEnterRoomShown"`

This should prevent the node from getting destoryed.